# handlebars template inside template

Tags: javascript, mustache, handlebars.js

How can I create a template inside a template in handlebars?
Those are my templates:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="animal-template">
    <div class="locationSelect">
    {{content}}
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="cat-template">
    <div>
    I am cat
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="dog-template">
    <div>
    I am dog
    </div>
</script>
```

I want to load the appropriated template at runtime (cat-template or dog-template) inside animal-template. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Partials** come in handy when you have a chunk of a Handlebars.js template that you need to use in a few different contexts

```
<script id="people-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each people}}
    {{> person}}
  {{/each}}
</script>

<script id="person-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="person">
    <h2>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</h2>
    <div class="phone">{{phone}}</div>
    <div class="email"><a href="mailto:{{email}}">{{email}}</a></div>
    <div class="since">User since {{member_since}}</div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var template = Handlebars.compile($("#people-template").html());
    Handlebars.registerPartial("person", $("#person-partial").html());

    template(yourData);
  }
</script>
```

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers

Comment: we generally don't much link 'link-only' answers here, but you did provide more than the link.  Probably this is about the 'slimmest' valid answer, FYI.  Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can compute `templateName`'s item view property according to the rendered item:

```js
App.AnimalView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateNameBinding: function () {
    var kind = this.get('animal.kind');
    return '%@-template'.fmt(kind);
  }.property('animal.kind')
});
```

Then in the container template, render the items through their view:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="animal-template">
  <div class="locationSelect">
  {{#for animal in content}}
    {{view App.AnimalView animalBinding="animal"}}
  {{/for}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Actually I am looking for a solution that is not dependent to Ember since I made this for jquery plugin.

Comment: In this case, you should not tag your question as [tag:ember.js]... :-)

Comment: I thought Ember.js users may know how to solve it without ember.. :) I will remove ember tag.